# Sort an Alphanumeric 2D Array Numerically

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I just required some help with my Python code which I am trying to create. This sorts a '2D Array' which contains both Numbers and Letters (Alphanumeric) to be sorted Numerically. So I have the below Array:

```
Array = (['Apple',1],['Banana',8],['Grape',120],['Pineapple',80])
```

And I was looking for an output which would sort numerically highest - lowest, for example I need the below output or similar:

```
(['Grape',120],['Pineapple',80],['Banana',8],['Apple',1])
```

Or something like this

```
Grape, 120
Pineapple, 80
Banana, 8
Apple, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in sorted operation:

```
sorted(Array, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Just tried it and this works, thank you so much! Does the Lambda key do, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @DW_0505,  you look at the dupe, you should probably also use itemgetter not a lambda

Comment: @PadraicCunningham May I ask you what do you mean?(_you look at the dupe,_)

Comment: @EbraHim, the duplicate question.

Comment: It is explained in the duplicate question, but the key argument just takes a function that transforms the item for comparison. In this case we just take the second element of the list (index 1). lambda just creates an anonymous function that takes some number of arguments (1 in this case: x), and returns some output (x[1] in this case).

Comment: @Jggrnaut Okay thanks